# Python C API: how to get string representation of exception?

Tags: python, exception, python-c-api

If I do (e.g.)

```
 open("/snafu/fnord")
```

in Python (and the file does not exist), I get a traceback and the message

```
 IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/snafu/fnord'
```

I would like to get the above string with Python's C API (i.e., a Python interpreter embedded in a C program). I need it as a string, not output to the console.

With `PyErr_Fetch()` I can get the type object of the exception and the value. For the above example, the value is a tuple:

```
 (2, 'No such file or directory', '/snafu/fnord')
```

Is there an easy way from the information I get from `PyErr_Fetch()` to the string the Python interpreter shows? (One that does not involve to construct such strings for each exception type yourself.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that Python exceptions are printed by running "str()" on the exception instance, which will return the formatted string you're interested in. You can get this from C by calling the [`PyObject_Str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_Str) method described here:

https://docs.python.org/c-api/object.html

Good luck!

**Update:** I'm a bit confused why the second element being returned to you by `PyErr_Fetch()` is a string. My guess is that you are receiving an "unnormalized exception" and need to call `PyErr_NormalizeException()` to turn that tuple into a "real" Exception that can format itself as a string like you want it to.

Comment: The second argument is a tuple and not a string. And I already call PyErr_NormalizeException(). But PyErr_Fetch() does not return an exception object, only the exception type. So I have to create the exception object myself, I guess? And I pass the second argument of PyErr_Fetch() to the constructor?

Comment: Oh, just checked my code and I did not call PyErr_NormalizeException() in all cases. Calling it, indeed turns the second argument into an exception object. And converting that one to a string with PyObject_Str() gets me the desired result. Thanks a lot.